# Compining ios native with phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I am building a ios app, in that I want a page like in Instagram app share with facebook, twitter etc. For this can I use Phonegap only for this page? Rest of my pages are native ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Embedding Cordova WebView on iOS](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20iOS). I haven't done this but it says you can use Cordova as a component in your project, so you can call up the webview at any point you want, instead of using it as the whole app.